# Finding the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**I'm having trouble with question c) as it is asking to find the differential equation for the diameter given the equation $D=aM^{1/3}$**
[image]

[image]

**My attempt**

[image]

[image]

**Why is my differential equation wrong?**